# How to open chrome-extension in new tab by default

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How to open chrome-extension in new tab by default? Not in the new pop-up as like the present time.
I have the:

```
//manifest.json    
{
    ...
    "background": {
            "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
            "persistent": false
        },
    "browser_action": {
            "default_title": "Test Viewer v.1.0",
            "default_icon": "icon.png",
            "default_popup": "index.html"
        },
    "permissions": [
            "unlimitedStorage",
            "notifications",
            "activeTab",
            "tabs",
            "https://docs.google.com/*",
            "downloads"
        ]
    ...
    }
```

and

```
//background.js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
     chrome.tabs.create({
        url: ("index.html"),
        type: "normal"
    });
});
```

In the docs https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows this type is specified as `type: "normal"` which open the "normal browser window" as I wish, but it doesn't work. 
Where is error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) I have deleted `default_popup` property in `manifest.json` by advice @Josh Lee and 2) use this code in `background.js`:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.create({
        'url': chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html#window")
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of `default_popup`. The presence of this attribute declaratively means you want to open your extension's popup when clicked.

As long as the `browser_action` section is present at all, you can use the `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` event to run your handler.

Comment: Ok, but where in the `manifest.json` i point the file `index.html` if I get rid of `default_popup` ?

Comment: You don't need to put index.html anywhere in the manifest, you can open it with chrome.tabs.create all the same.